# Ground state energy of spin 1 particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, hamiltonian, ground-state

So I have this Hamiltonian for a particle with spin 1:
$$ H=aS_{z}^2+\frac{\hbar\omega}{\sqrt2}S_{x}$$
where ($a$ and $\omega$ both real constants):

$$ S_{z}=\hbar\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -1
 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ and\ \ \ \ S_{x}=\hbar\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
and what I want to find out is the energy of the ground state for this system.
What I tried was solving the Schrodinger equation for time independent systems and I got values for the energy ( i.e, I solved a eigenvalue equation and got these):
$$ E=a\hbar^2 \ ;E=\hbar^2\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2+2\omega^2}}{2}$$

Edit: So assuming the $E=\hbar^2\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+2\omega^2}}{2}$ is the energy of the ground state, if I want to determine the ground state itself I just determine the eigenvector for this engenvalue?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform ground state means it has the lowest energy possible but the thing is I don't know anything about these constants ..

Comment: $ \hbar^2\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+\omega^2}}{2} > a\hbar^2 >\hbar^2\frac{a -\sqrt{a^2+\omega^2}}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyportnex is right: you can be sure that the energy of the ground state (i.e. the energy of the state with least energy) is $E=\hbar^2\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+2\omega^2}}{2}$, by simply comparing the values that you got.
Furthermore, if what you want now is to find out the representation of the ground state itself, you just solve the linear system
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
a\hbar^2 & \frac{\hbar^2\omega}{2} & 0 \\
\frac{\hbar^2\omega}{2} & 0 & \frac{\hbar^2\omega}{2} \\
0 & \frac{\hbar^2\omega}{2} & a\hbar^2
\end{pmatrix} = \hbar^2\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+2\omega^2}}{2} \ 
\begin{pmatrix}
\xi \\ \eta \\ \zeta
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
from where you'll find that $\xi=\zeta$ and $\eta=\frac{2\omega}{a-\sqrt{a^2+2\omega^2}}\xi$ .

The normalised eigenvector is therefore

\begin{equation}
|\ \lambda\ \rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+\Lambda^2}} \ \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ \Lambda \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\Lambda=\frac{2\omega}{a-\sqrt{a^2+2\omega^2}}$.